# права доступа и ошибки в логах PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, hosting, доступ, vds

итак,

предыстория:

1. на vds сервере были распакованы из архива файлы некого сайта, пользователем
   root
2. в связи с чем была некорректная работа того, что находится в папке cache.
3. далее - был изменен пользователь с root на www-root только для одной папки, с которой была связана ошибка:

`sudo chown -R www-root:www-root /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.ru/cache/static/`

в итоге, то, что явно не работало - работает, но большое НО - в логе гора ошибок PHP

**Собственно вопрос:**
Есть ли необходимость всем оставшимся папкам и файлам сайта назначить владельца www-root?  (вместо root)
 а именно:
`sudo chown -R www-root:www-root /var/www`
Могут ли неправильно выставленные права доступа (неверный пользователь) приводить к  множественным ошибкам вроде  `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /.../?`

Comment: Нет, не похоже что ошибка из за этого. Может быть у вас раньше были отключены notice?

Comment: Спасибо, да, это имело место быть

Comment: Ошибки `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /.../` оказались связаны с конфликтом версий PHP. Версия на сервере - PHP7, а проект на PHP5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильные права такие - пользователь - разработчик который будет менять файлы, с правами на запись, группа - та же от которой работает апач, с правами на чтение, и если из скриптов что-то пишется в файлы, типа кеша темплейтов например, то права группе на запись. Директориям права на запуск для пользователя и группы. остальным никаких прав.